# Why doesn't "go get gopkg.in/..." work while "go get github.com/..." OK?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, github, go

I try to use `go get gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2` to install [pool](https://github.com/fatih/pool) according to `Readme.md`, but can't success:

```
C:\Users\xiaona\Documents\GitHub> go get -v gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2
Fetching https://gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2?go-get=1
https fetch failed.
Fetching http://gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2?go-get=1
import "gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2": http/https fetch: Get http://gopkg.in/fatih/poo
l.v2?go-get=1: dial tcp 107.178.216.236:80: ConnectEx tcp: A connection attempt
failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of ti
me, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respon
d.
package gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2
"
```

While access `107.178.216.236:80` is OK in web browser.

I try to use `go get github.com/fatih/pool`, and it also works OK.

Could anyone give some clues on this issue?

BTW: I use `windows powershell` and `git` version is `1.9.5`.

Comment: I tried on my Mac OSX shell and worked just fine. It looked like there's something wrong with the https implementation on the other side. Perhaps you can try again?

Comment: Check if your `go get` initiates a proper HTTPS handshake (via Wireshark or a similar network sniffing action), if there's a HTTPS request failure, you might need to update your Go installation to stop using SSLv3 and/or obsolete ciphersuites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause has been found: Because my computer use a web proxy, so I need to set proxy in environment variable:

```
C:\Users\xiaona>set https_proxy=https://web-proxy.corp.hp.com:8080/

C:\Users\xiaona>set http_proxy=https://web-proxy.corp.hp.com:8080/

C:\Users\xiaona>go get -v gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2
Fetching https://gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2?go-get=1 (status code 200)

get "gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"gopkg.in/fa
tih/pool.v2", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2"} at https://g
opkg.in/fatih/pool.v2?go-get=1
gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2 (download)
gopkg.in/fatih/pool.v2
```

Then, all is OK!